# Laggy MacBook Pro on High Sierra and 2 external displays

Tags: macbook-pro, display, high-sierra, performance

I've got a late 2013, 15-inch retina MacBook Pro.

Since a couple macOS upgrades ago, my system has become randomly slow, borderline unusable. I've come to realize it spikes when using 3 displays (2 external 1080p and laptop's retina screen). If I close the laptop and only use the 2 external displays, CPU usage instantly drops. And then, if I open it again, rises up and `kernel_task` can report over 150% CPU usage and transitions, typing, everything becomes laggy. This can happen even on a fresh boot.

I'm clueless, since 3 displays should be effortless on the GPUs task and by no means take over the CPU. I read `kernel_task` might spike in order to prevent other processes to hog the CPU and overheat. Even then, closing the screen interrupts no CPU consuming processes, so that shouldn't calm `kernel_task` down. And the laptop should be even hotter while closed than open.

Is there a step that might help resolve the slowdown?

Comment: What version of the MacBook Pro do you have? Specifically does it have external or integrated graphics?

Comment: @ozliftoff It's a 15 Inch RMBP, as stated above. Identifier is `MacBookPro11,3`. It has both an Intel Iris and Nvidia GT750M

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why I didn't try this earlier, but a [SMC Reset](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295) did it.

So I guess sensors were a little off and that was it? Any additional technical details is still much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Restarting SMC chipset helped fixing it.

- Shut down Mac
- Hold. CTRL+OPTION+SHIFT+POWER button for 10 seconds
- Start mac

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. How is this different than the main answer here? Perhaps making a suggested edit would be better than posting the same answer on several questions.

Comment: Not only is this not different, you're cutting and pasting the exact same answer for multiple questions:  [Question 1](https://bit.ly/39UyQE9), [Question 2](https://bit.ly/3k7c7tf) and [Question 3](https://bit.ly/30qaSO6) .  Thus far, all of your answers.  See [How to write a good answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) for tips on writing an answer that will get attention and ultimately up voted.

Answer (score 0):

The answer from Kuldip was the correct answer for me, but without explanation, I wouldn't have tried it.  Here is another thread that goes into slightly more detail (also answered by Kuldip)

[OS slows down when I connect external monitor](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/387997/os-slows-down-when-i-connect-external-monitor)

Context: My girlfriend's mac pro with 8G was behaving so poorly, as if it was heavily swaping/paging.  But I could find no evidence of that using Top.  She has two port replicators plugged into the USB C ports with a monitor on each (so 3 monitors total).  Restarting the SMC chipset saved the laptop from getting flung out the window.